# understanding orientation in tabBar application iOS 4.2

Tags: iphone, ios

I am currently working on a tabBar application.  My tabBar controller is the rootViewController and I have 3 tabs.  Each tab will have several UIWebView's on them which I would like to be able to support orientation once the webview has loaded.  Once the webview has closed then orientation is no longer supported.  How can I tell my other viewControllers to handle orientation instead of the rootViewController?

I hope I explained this to where it's clear.

As always TIA,

T

Comment: I dont understand at all.  Do you want your web views to respond to orientation changes when they are first loaded?

Comment: @Robert - Yes I would like the web views to respond.  I will be streaming life and pre-recorded content via the web views.  Everything is working with exception of being able to handle rotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this is a shot in the dark - This might not be what you are asking.

To support multiple orientations you need to do 2 things.

1. Check the orientation when the ViewController is first loaded.
2. Respond to orientation changed notifications / override orientation changed methods.

Here is how I do it:

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation 
{
    // Call my method to handle orientations
    [self layoutViewsForOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation];
    return YES;
}

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{
    // ...
    // Some code .....
    // ...
    // Call my method to handle orientations
    [self layoutViewsForOrientation:self.interfaceOrientation];
}


- (void) layoutViewsForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation) orientation 
{
    UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation) {
        // Move views about if needed
    } else {
        // ....
    }
}
```